# Use of gerund without preposition "to"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, gerunds, transitivity

Can I use gerunds with the word "concede" without using preposition "to" as in the sentence below?

> He concedes killing his wife.

Comment: Where did the idea that _to_ is used with gerunds come from? _To_ is used with **infinitives**, not gerunds.

Comment: John, surely you are right, but I often see *to-gerund* constructs.

Comment: One admits to a crime, but one concedes an argument to an opponent. One might concede *that* one killed one's wife.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Examples? Those are just prepositional uses anyway, like *from walking to running in five easy steps*.

Comment: There are lots of constructions with gerund phrases (i.e, reduced gerund clauses) as objects of a preposition. Usually the preposition is governed by the preceding verb, like _He admitted to/She looked into/They argued over robbing the bank_. But it doesn't have anything to do with the gerund.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, it appears that [no one says ***any*** of those](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=concedes+killing%2Cconcedes+to+killing%2Cconcedes+to+having+killed&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=), perhaps because *concede* does not work that way:

[image: conceded graph]

On the other hand, if you [swap *admits* in for *concedes*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admits+killing%2Cadmits+to+killing%2Cadmits+to+having+killed&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=), now you get a more interesting picture:

[image: admits graph]

And here is [the past-tense version of the same](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admitted+killing%2Cadmitted+to+killing%2Cadmitted+to+having+killed&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=):

[image: admitted]

I find especially curious that this only started getting said come the 20<sup>th</sup> century.  That part I don’t know what to make of.

In any event, it appears that ***admitting doing*** anything is fairly new to the English language, and  following that *admit* with a *to* before an *-ing* form is a very recent phenomenon indeed.

Comment: so it means no?

Comment: @user41412 Right: it shows that people neither *“concede doing things”* nor *“concede **to** doing”* things. You want to use *admit* there instead.